# How many times will I get X before getting Y N times or Z 1 time

Tags: probability, geometric-distribution

First, I come from a Computer Engineering (software) background, not Math, so any Math formula that aren’t pemdas aren’t going to be super helpful or insightful for me.

Now, the problem I’m trying to solve. I’m porting some old software over to a new environment and I need the behavior to remain the same. But I’d like to improve the efficiency of the algorithm over the original naive approach.

```
Pass = 0
Fail = 0
while Pass < Total:
    Percent = Random( 1 to 100 inclusive )
    if Percent < 97
        Pass += 1
    else if Percent = 97
        break
    else if Percent > 97
        Fail += 1

Pass = Total
return Pass, Fail
```

I'll try to state the algorithm in English here.  Roll a 100 side dice until Total Passes have been achieved.  If the result of the roll is less than 97 its a Pass, if the result is more than 97 its a Fail, if the result is 97 no more Fails can occur.

I’d like to completely get rid of the loop by calculating the probability of a Fail result for any number of Totals.

```
Failures = Weighted Random( 1 to Total, with weights[ 1 to Total ] )
```

I’m unsure how to calculate the weights. 3% of the time the Result should be Fail until 1% of the time Fail is no longer a valid choice. I wrote a program that ran the original algorithm with 3 as the Total. Before I got 3 Passes, I got this many failures, this frequently:

```
Fail Count, Frequency
         0, 0.91353420
         1, 0.08134433
         2, 0.00486673
         3, 0.00024296
         4, 0.00001138
         5, 0.00000039
         6, 0.00000001
```

I couldn’t work out how to scale the weights to match.

Anyways, any help would be appreciated. I don’t mind reading up on specific math topics, but I’m unsure what this problem even falls under.

Edited to be clearer and added measured weights

Edit: This is the solution I came up with thanks to WW1 and Misha Lavrov's help below.

```
def P( n, t ):
    return binomialcoeff( t + n - 1, n ) * pow( 0.96, t ) * pow( 0.03, n )
```

```
# 0 0.88473600
# 1 0.07962624
# 2 0.00477757
# 3 0.00023888
# 4 0.00001075
# 5 0.00000045
# 6 0.00000002
```

```
def S( n, t ):
    sigma = 0
    for k in 0 to t - 1 inclusive:
        sigma += binomialcoeff( n + k, k ) * pow( 0.96, k ) * pow( 0.03, n )
    return sigma * 0.01
```

```
# 0 0.02881600
# 1 0.00170544
# 2 0.00008469
# 3 0.00000380
# 4 0.00000016
# 5 0.00000001
# 6 0.00000000
```

Comment: "Now, the problem I’m trying to solve. I’m porting some old software over to a new environment and I need the behavior to remain the same. But I’d like to improve the efficiency of the algorithm over the original naive approach." What exactly is the problem you are working on? What is the goal?

Comment: "I’m unsure how to calculate the weights." What are the weights supposed to do? What is the desired functionality?

Comment: The goal is to remove the loop, by picking with the same frequency an amount Nothing results, the N until M. The weights tell the random generator with what frequency to pick each member of a population.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of $n$ failures when your total is $t$ is given by...

$$ P(n, t)= \binom{t+n-1}n(0.96)^t(0.03)^n+(0.01)\sum_{k=0}^{t-1}\binom{n+k}k(0.96)^k(0.03)^n
$$
You will need to make a decision about what will be your highest value of $n$

Brief explanation

Either...

- you make $n+t$ rolls with $t$ passes and $n$ fails with the last roll being a pass
- you make $n+k+1$ rolls with $k$ passes (sum over all $k<t$) and $n$ fails, and the last roll is a 97

Comment: I've coded up the formula, but I must not be reading it correctly.  See the edit to my original post.

Comment: get rid of the + 0.01. in the first formula, multiply the result of the second formula by 0.01, have the sum include k=0

Comment: If I include 0, I'd have to divide by 0, which most CPUs take exception to.  I did move the 0.01 from one to the other those.  Updated the original post with the results.  Still not quite right, but I'm digging into geometric distribution now.

Comment: @JasonBrown There's no *division*. You seem to be computing $\frac{n+k}{k}$ instead of the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) $\binom{n+k}{k}$.

Comment: @Misha Lavrov, Yes that's exactly it.  I'll look at binomial coefficients and see if I can correct the code.  Thank you.

Comment: @JasonBrown The easiest way to compute them is probably recursively. When $k=0$, $\binom{n+k}{k}=1$. For $k\ge 1$, $\binom{n+k}{k} = \frac{n+k}{k} \binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$, which is $\frac{n+k}{k}$ times the previous case. When you're done with the sum and $k=t-1$, you've already found $\binom{n+t-1}{t-1}$, which is equal to $\binom{n+t-1}{n}$, the value you want for the term outside the sum.

Comment: The Sigma still didn't come out right, but the other one is within acceptable tolerances of the original.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your sigma formula looks correct, but somehow the sum is not including the third term ($k=2$)

Comment: here are my results for $t=3$ 
 https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bexldneeej

Comment: @WW1, yes it was a bug in my code that wasn't including the k=2.  I didn't realize I was supposed to add the formula together to get the final product.  Looking at your desmos, I can replicate it now thank you.